# Botão Voltar com Registros pesquisados

Tags: php, zend, framework

Estou com um botão que no momento só é um botão:

```
<button type="button" name="voltar" id="voltar" class="btn btn-default" style="margin-left: 30px">Cancelar</button>

$('#voltar').click(function() {

        alert('voltar');

    });
```

Mas preciso que ele volte para a tela onde estão todos os registros pesquisados e de preferência para pagina exata, como faria isso?

### Resolvido de forma paleativa

header("Location:./consultar". $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']);

Ainda não é exatamente o que queria, mas vai servir por enquanto.

Comment: se for só voltar da pra usar ali no lugar de alert history.go(-1)

Comment: possível duplicata de [Botão Voltar no registro de uma consulta](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/52274/bot%c3%a3o-voltar-no-registro-de-uma-consulta)

Comment: Não funciona assim, mano.. não é o resultado certo. =\

Answer (score 1):

Se você estiver desenvolvendo com Zend Framework use o helper de URL (de acordo com a sua versão do Zend Framework) para construir um link com o elemento `<a>`

[Zend Framework 1](http://framework.zend.com/manual/1.12/en/zend.view.helpers.html#zend.view.helpers.initial)

[Zend Framework 2](http://framework.zend.com/manual/current/en/modules/zend.view.helpers.url.html)